# iOS: Are there any ways to use paid info of users of my app number one in other app number two?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

We have an old paid app and now we want to develop other one free app with in-app purchases. It won't be a new version of first one - fully new app. So, I have a problem with understanding the possibility of providing the use of a new app to users who have purchased an old app. I found a similar question - [iOS: Tracking the paid users while converting paid iOS application to free with in-app purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846056/ios-tracking-the-paid-users-while-converting-paid-ios-application-to-free-with) - about the release of a new free version of the app, but in my case, I need to release a new app. Is it possible? Or do I need to convince the bosses to just release a new version of the old app?